# Convert MySQL Query to Laravel 4.2 Query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

My MySQL Query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT `car`.`car_maker` as `brand`, `car`.`car_model` AS `model`, `available_car`.`car_price` AS `price`, `car`.`car_production_year` AS `year`, `available_car`.`car_id` AS `car_id`,`available_car`.`id` AS `id`, `available_car`.`current_position`  AS `current_position`
    FROM `car`, `available_car`, `users`
        WHERE `available_car`.`car_id`=`car`.`car_id`
            AND `available_car`.`is_sold` =  'no'
            AND `available_car`.`created_at` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
                ORDER BY WEEK(`available_car`.`created_at`) DESC,
                        `available_car`.`car_price`DESC,
                        `users`.`last_paid_date` DESC,
                        `available_car`.`created_at` DESC
```

How Can I convert it Using Laravel Query builder?

I want to have it like this type of query -

```
$info = DB::table('car` , `available_car`, `users')
            ->select('car.car_maker', 'car.car_model', 'available_car.car_price', 'car.car_production_year', 'available_car.car_id','available_car.id', 'available_car.current_position')
            ->get();
```

But it is not working.

My Database is like this

[image]

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
DB::table('car')
->join('available_car', 'car.car_id', '=', 'availabe_car.car_id')
->join('users', 'available_car.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
->where('available_car.is_sold', 'no')
->whereRaw('available_car.created_at BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()')
->orderByRaw('WEEK(`available_car`.`created_at`) DESC')
->orderBy('available_car.car_price', 'desc')
->orderBy('users.last_paid_date', 'desc')
->orderBy('available_car.created_at', 'desc')
->select('car.car_maker as brand', 'car.car_model as model', 'available_car.car_price as price', 'car.car_production_year as year', 'available_car.car_id as car_id', 'available_car.id as id', 'available_car.current_position as current_position')
->distinct()->get()
```

Note that this is untested code.

Comment: select d1.update_id from ( select update_id, count(update_id) as ct from updates_tags where tag_id in (67,33,86,55) group by update_id) as d1 where d1.ct=4

How to convert this into laravel query....?

Comment: @Ankit Please post your question as a separate question. Comments are for follow-up questions and discussion

Comment: @lukasgeiter I am not able put that new question something went wrong...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36260657/apply-and-operation-in-laravel-select-query

You can answer it at here... here is my question... please answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass multiple table to `select` because they will be escaped as a whole. As an alternative to @lukasgeiter's solution that uses inner joins, you could use `DB::raw` inside `table()`:

```
DB::table(DB::raw('`car` , `available_car`, `users`'))
    ->select('car.car_maker', 'car.car_model', 'available_car.car_price', 'car.car_production_year', 'available_car.car_id', 'available_car.id', 'available_car.current_position')
    ->where('available_car.car_id', '`car`.`car_id`')
    ->where('available_car.is_sold', 'no')
    ->whereRaw('`available_car`.`created_at` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()')
    ->orderByRaw('WEEK(`available_car`.`created_at`) DESC')
    ->orderBy('available_car.car_price', 'desc')
    ->orderBy('users.last_paid_date', 'desc')
    ->orderBy('available_car.created_at', 'desc')
    ->distinct()
    ->get();
```

Comment: Ye with `DB::raw` you can do pretty much everything. I like joins more though ;)

Comment: @lukasgeiter I like joins more as well. I only offered it as an alternative because this builds an identical query to the one posted in the question.