# Query Execution

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

How to execute this query in laravel. ?

```
  select d1.update_id from ( select update_id, count(update_id) 
  as ct from updates_tags where tag_id in (67,33,86,55) group by 
  update_id) as d1 where d1.ct=4
```

Comment: for those types of query you can use whereRaw()

Comment: not getting results. i want to use this for filter based on the t_id. If multiple t_id is contains the same u_id then it should be print.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Raw Queries in Laravel

```
$results = DB::select(SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4) AND );
```

http://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries

Answer (score 0):

You can chain `where` conditions with eloquent, each chained one is evaluated like an `and`.

`$update  = Tag::whereIn('t_id',$tags)->whereIn('u_id',$tags)->where(/*more and conditions you could need*/)->lists('u_id')`

Edit: If you need the ones coincident with u_id consider this:

```
$update = DB::table('tags')
->select('t_id', 'u_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
->whereIn('t_id',$tags)
->where('total','=',count($tags))
->groupBy('u_id')
->lists('u_id');
```

Comment: i want to use this for filter based on the t_id. If multiple t_id is contains the same u_id then it should be print. There may be multiple t_id at a time 2 or 4 how can i check ?

Comment: vivoconunxino: I want the u_id list not t_id. I am begginer in the laravel. If t_id(11,21) same u_id then I need that u_id.

Comment: Please, check and try edits

Comment: vivoconunxino  it is working half way but when I apply only t_id it is showing other u_id records as well which is not even contain that u_id.

Comment: what are you meaning with 'I apply only t_id' ? Also, does your table contain rows with empty u_id?

Comment: Let me explain what i want to get. i have tags in my filters and some of the news contains the tags if I enter any tag id to serve it shows me that tag related to news. But when I apply multiple tag ids at that time i need to check that particular tags contains any specific news or not. when there is multiple tags I need to check which news is contains same tag ids if any news contains that particular tag_ids then that news will be seen

Comment: Now I think I know what you want to accomplish. To tell you the truth it's hard to guess from your question.. check edits

Comment: vivoconunixino why you put total parameter in the DB::Raw ? I am not able to understand that thing. total for no. of tag_ids ? but SQL consider that as a column. what should i do ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107599/discussion-between-ankit-and-vivoconunxino).